# Seperate th and td in table with css

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a table responsive for mobile devices, and I made the td and th display value block, so that made it a little better. Only problem is, the headings are all stacked on eachother in a group, and the data is all stacked together in their own group. I want to make it so the headings are first, then data for that specific row, then the next heading and data, and so on. I  want to get this done using only CSS. Below is the code i just copied and pasted. I don't really want to mess up anything with the PHP because  do not fully understand it. his is what i want to display: one single th with the data that goes with it underneath it, then after td the next th and its td, and so on.  I included my code in a jsfidle in the summary of this question because the tab would not work on my computer.

Comment: Could you please share your code, preferably in a jsfiddle? Seeing what you've done is the only way to help you in any practical manner.

Comment: Questions should contain code in the question itself. Do not rely on a jsfiddle alone. Better still include a working example in your question by using the snippets feature, the `<>` button in the editor.

Comment: Can you also clarify what you want as the end result as it is somewhat unclear at the moment?

Comment: Could you please share your code in snippet or fiddle? Only then we can determine how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I couldn't add a short enough comment for some reason but I edited my question and include the jsfiddle link in the summary

Answer (score 0):

From your statement

> I made the td and th display value block, so that made it a little better. Only problem is, the headings are all stacked on eachother in a group, and the data is all stacked together in their own group.

Adding `display:block` to the `th` and `td`  will make your contents stack up in one cell and it would look like this:

```
header1
content1
content2
content3
header2
content1
content2
content3
```

or

```
header1
header2
content1
content2
content3
content1
content2
content3
```

> I want to make it so the headings are first, then data for that specific row, then the next heading and data, and so on.

I'm guessing that you want your table to be like this:

```
header1 | content1 | content2 | content 3
header2 | content1 | content2 | content 3
header3 | content1 | content2 | content 3
```

Here is an example in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwzfrs27/)**

**UPDATE**

From your jsfiddle, do you really not have a `<tr>` in a table? Because `<tr>` is the one will separate your `<th>` from `<td>`. I added a `<tr>` from your jsfiddle and it looks like this:

[image]

Is that the table that you want?
Here is the **[Jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBjJB.png)**.

Comment: The first sample of code you provided @user3771102 is how I want the table to display, and the second table is how the table is set up currently.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fws1x7os/           that is my jsfiddle link. The table is set up with the td seperate from the th, and I think that is the problem, but I don't want to mess up the original php that is working if i nest the td inside the th. I want to find a way to fix this using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First you can put your table header cells in a `thead` element and the other table cells in a `tbody`. After you can copy and prepend the `th` of the `thead` before all the first `td` of the `tbody`'s `tr`. Sorry it's not easy to made it clear. Here's an example

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header1</th>
                <th>header2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>header1</th><!-- as in the thead -->
                <td>Content1</td>
                <td>Content2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>header2</th><!-- as in the thead -->
                <td>Content1</td>
                <td>Content2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the CSS, when you are in mobile you should hide the `thead` and show only the `tbody th`. In tablet/desktop you do the reverse.

```
<style>
     /* Mobile first */
     table,
     thead,
     tbody,
     tr,
     th,
     td {
         display:block;
     }

     th,
     td {
         text-align:left;
     }

     th {
         background:#f00;
     }

     td {
         background:#0099ff;
     }

     thead {
         display:none;
     }

     tr {
         margin-bottom:16px;
     }

     /* When you going up 768px */
     @media screen and (min-width:768px) {
         table {
             border:2px solid #000;
             display:table;
             width:100%;
         }

         tr {
             display:table-row;
         }

         td,
         th {
             display:table-cell;                 
         }

         thead,
         tbody {
             display:table-header-group;
         }

         tbody th {
             display:none;
         }             
     }
    </style>
```

The fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uc8q0u96/.

It could be cleaner to create data attributes on all the first `td` of the `tbody`'s `tr` and put the content of the corresponding header cell:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header1</th>
                <th>header2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>                    
                <td data-header="header1">Content1</td>
                <td>Content2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                    
                <td data-header="header2">Content1</td>
                <td>Content2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And using a `::before` pseudo element to fetch the content of the `data-header` attribute in CSS:

```
/* Mobile first */
     table,
     thead,
     tbody,
     tr,
     th,
     td {
         display:block;
     }

     td[data-header]:before {
         background:yellowgreen;
         content:attr(data-header);
         display:block;
     }

     th,
     td {
         text-align:left;
     }

     th {
         background:#f00;
     }

     td {
         background:#0099ff;
     }

     thead {
         display:none;
     }

     tr {
         margin-bottom:16px;
     }

     /* When you going up 768px */
     @media screen and (min-width:768px) {
         table {
             border:2px solid #000;
             display:table;
             width:100%;
         }

         tr {
             display:table-row;
         }

         td,
         th {
             display:table-cell;                 
         }

         thead,
         tbody {
             display:table-header-group;
         }

         td[data-header]:before {
             display:none;
         }
     }
```

The fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o9mtfsdL/3.

Voilà.